# Is there a minimal order of an uncomputable function that bounds all computable functions?

Tags: complexity-theory

Busy Beaver is an uncomputable function that grows quicker than any computable function. That means there exist functions f such that for all computable functions g: g in O(f). There is an upper bound on the order of computable functions.

[Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/152716/is-there-a-maximal-order-of-computable-functions) I asked whether there is a computable function bounding all computable functions (There isn't).

Is there, though, among uncomputable functions, a minimal order function h such that

$$ \forall g:g\ computable \implies g \in O(h) $$
$$ \forall f: (\forall g:g\ computable \implies g \in O(f)) \implies f \in \Omega(h)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $h$ is such that $g = O(h)$ for all computable $g$. Let $H(n) = h(n)/n$. I claim that $H$ also satisfies $g = O(H)$ for all computable $g$. Otherwise, let $g$ be a computable function such that $g$ is not $O(H)$. In particular, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $g(n) \geq H(n)$, and so $n g(n) \geq h(n)$. Let $G(n) = n^2 g(n)$, which is computable. Since $G(n) \geq n h(n)$ for infinitely many $n$, it is not the case that $G = O(h)$, contradicting the assumption on $h$.

Comment: Nice proof, thanks. That means that, together with my other question, while there is a boundary, it is no specific function. No function exists that IS the boundary. Right?

Comment: This is known in the literature as a “gap”.

Comment: There are many functions f(x) such that if g(n) is computable, then so is f(g(n)). For example f(x) = x!. Then H(n) = f^(-1) (h(n)) also satisfies g = O(H). So the gap is more than any computable function. Or instead of x! take the 100th Ackermann function.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Do you know literature that explores this gap and can point me there? It's driving me crazy that there even is this fundamental boundary, that it can't even be described by a function makes it even more mysterious to me.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in particular. You should check classical texts on recursion theory, such as Odifreddi.

Comment: @kutschkem, you are basically asking how fast computable functions can grow. But if f(n) is computable, then f(f(n)) is also computable. Now consider the small Ackermann functions, which are all computable. The third one goes quickly beyond astronomical values. A3(5) cannot be anywhere near written down in the universe, and that unimaginable number is about the number of digits in A3(6). But if f(n) is computable, then A100(f(n)) is computable.

Comment: You might be interested in the fast growing hierarchy.